# Geoserver projection recognize problem

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, well-known-text, epsg, curl

I'm publishing shape files in geoserver through curl,my problem is that geoserver didn't recognizing the projection which is in ESRI WKT format(layer was publishing).I searched for this problem i found that ESRI wkt format don't have the "EPSG:4326" .
What i have to do to recognize the ESRI wkt format projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options:

**.prj file**

Create a .prj file which contains the EPSG:4326 that GeoServer does recognise. You can get this from the `Demos -> SRS List` admin page. Name this .prj file the same as your shapefile and if necessary overwrite the one that exists.

**Force declared**

When adding the layer, set the "Declared SRS to 4326" and the SRS Handling to "force declared".

[image]

See: 
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html#coordinate-reference-systems

Comment: I believe that OP is doing this using curl on the REST enpoint. Can you show the parameters that one can use with the REST endpoint, to set the declared SRS?